# How to make thread-local library instance?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, shared-libraries

We use legacy library at our workplace. It contains some business logic and it's code was lost before the change of millennia. Code contains some hard financial algorithms, it actively uses global variables.

We plan to make some calculations parallel, launching new threads. Every thread will be independent from another, just a blackbox returning some number.

Core problem is that library isn't thread-safe. We would like to somehow make that every thread has it's own copy of global variables, code, etc. from shared library.

Is this possible? Currently, we just patch symbol names and make copies with prefixes.

`library-thread1.so`, `library-thread2.so` and etc.

Symbols are loaded using `RTLD_DEEPBIND` under linux.

**EDIT:** Replacing threads with processes is most straitforward way to solve this, but it rises concerns about performance. And seems to be to much work, than just doing dirty hack.

Comment: It's certainly possible if you substitute "process" for "thread". Otherwise it _may_ be possible, but seems pretty brittle and error-prone.

Comment: At a prior job, we had a similar problem of needing one process to load different _versions_ of a library that was responsible for network communication with a service bus. This was necessary to allow one service to communicate with multiple buses that ran incompatible versions of the wire protocol. Our solution was to build a COM service and create out-of-process instances. You may be able to do the same thing: create an out-of-process COM service and create multiple instances. Of course there is some IPC overhead, but this may not be significant in your use case.

Comment: Global variables are *process* global, so a thread is not sufficient to isolate them. Consider spawning multiple individual *processes* when parallelizing your work.

Answer (score 1):

> Core problem is that library isn't thread-safe.

Use processes, not threads. The library will be multi-process-safe automatically, with no effort or risk of accidental sharing.

> We would like to somehow make that every thread has it's own copy of global variables, code, etc. from shared library.

Threads that have this property are called processes. Processes are - mostly - threads that don't share globals (including things including file descriptors, `std::cout` buffers etc. etc.).

Processes are not, on Linux or *NIX generally, massively more expensive, or slower to communicate with, than threads.

> Replacing threads with processes is most straitforward way to solve this, but it rises concerns about performance

So do it and then *measure* the performance. If it's really a problem, you can use shared memory on Linux to keep the effectively-zero-overhead communication of threads, while preserving correct semantics.

> And seems to be to much work, than just doing dirty hack.

Worry more about how much work it will be to *support* the dirty hack when it all goes wrong and you can't figure out why.

Comment: This certainly doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Well, your question pre-supposes a hard distinction between threads and processes, and between the performance of inter-process and inter-thread communications. This supposition is _wrong_, so a frame-challenge seems like a reasonable response. If you have a real rather than imaginary problem with processes, or you need help understanding how to use them, then ask _that_ question.

Comment: BTW I have absolutely no idea how to address this on Windows. Trying to lump two very different process models into one answer seems excessive anyway, but I don't know that the best solution is likely to be the same on both platforms.